# Length cannot be less than zero Parameter Name: length

Tags: c#, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have hunted hi and low to attempt to find a solution to this error.  In Debug and Release mode of VS2015 i do not get any errors and the code generates the desired outcome.  Once the program is compiled and installed, when the email button is pressed to generate the code, the application acts like its going to work and then after about 20 seconds the gives the error "Length cannot be less than zero Parameter Name: length" but the application continues but does not complete the code in question.

I have disabled and attempted the one line of code that references length which made no difference.

I at my limits of what could be causing this so i am looking for help to find the needle in a haystack.

Below is the code in question:

```
try
        {
            // Create the Outlook application.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            // Create a new mail item.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            // Set HTMLBody. 
            //add the body of the email
            oMsg.HTMLBody = DictMailParam["Body"].ToString();
            //Add an attachment.
            String sDisplayName = DictMailParam["AttachmentName"].ToString();
            int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
            int iAttachType = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
            //now attached the file
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add
            //                             (@"C:\\fileName.jpg", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);

            foreach (string strFile in DictMailParam["Attachments"].ToString().Split(',').ToList())
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add
                        (strFile, iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
            }
            //Subject line
            oMsg.Subject = DictMailParam["Subject"].ToString();
            // Add a recipient.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oRecip = null; 
            // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
            foreach (var MailId in DictMailParam["ToAddress"].ToString().Split(';').ToArray())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MailId))
                {
                    oRecip = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(MailId);//DictMailParam["ToAddress"].ToString()
                    oRecip.Resolve();
                    // Send.
                }

            }

            oMsg.Send();
            MessageBox.Show("Purchase Order has been sent to your email." + "\n" + "Please check your mail.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            // Clean up.
            oRecip = null;
            oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;
        }//end of try block
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }//end of catch
    }//end of Email Method
```

Comment: Which line does throw the exception?

Comment: Try writing out your stack trace from the exception as well. I can't see anything obviously wrong, but the stacktrace would give more information.

Comment: As Ben says, write out your stack trace too (`ex.ToString()`, not `ex.Message`).

Comment: Hi guys,  I just tried both and it still gives me the same error with no additional information.  Any ideas on what to try to solve this next?

Answer (score 0):

Change the catch code to MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()...) instead of ex.Message. This way when error happens you will get a message specifying which line is throwing the exception. Then come back here and tell which line it was. It will be much more easy to solve your problem once we know where it is.

Comment: That code is not supposed to fix the error. That code is supposed to tell us where the error is. Can you post here the exactly error text you are getting?

Comment: I get "Length cannot be less than zero Parameter Name: length" with the option of ok button to select.

Comment: I have attempted to put message boxes at intervals of the code thinking this could break down the sections but it does not change to the error message. There are two buttons with similar code, one does print preview (that works no error) and the other does not work and gives the error. I was thinking the call to the code could be wrong  this.CreateReport(0);  as the print preview option is 1 and the email is meant to be 0.  In the first line of the code for Create report it says private void CreateReport(int isPreview = 1)  could this be the problem?